# Floating point exception using function gethostbyname in static linked application

Tags: c++, linux, static-linking, gethostbyname

I have a code:

```
struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname(dns.c_str());
```

in my app. I compile it on Ubuntu server linking all statically. All ok, but when i try to start this app on CentOS i have a error in this gethostbyname calling:

> Floating point exception

Can you help me how to fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried recompiling it on CentOS? Usually you don't pass Linux-applications as binary...

Comment: @bash.d, i can recompile it, this is my client machine

Comment: So I assume that there are differences in the header files, so you might not be able to distribute your program as a binary...

Comment: Whenever I try statically linking the libc, I get a warning that certain functions (among which is gethostbyname) still require the .so files of exactly the same version of the glibc that they were statically linked against....

Comment: Apart from this, it seems that **gethostbyname**-function has been declared [deprecated](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostbynameman.html)! So you should not be using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static linking considered harmful
http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/no_static_linking.html

"all kinds of features in the libc (locale (through iconv), NSS, IDN, ...) require dynamic linking to load the appropriate external code."